# Multicast doesn't get forwarded correctly

Tags: routing, troubleshooting, multicast, udp

I have a problem with UDP-Multicast with Kubernetes:

I have to Kubernetes-Nodes each of them running a pod:

Kubernetes-Node-1:
   - eth0: 192.168.0.2/24
   - docker0: 10.1.1.1/24
Pod1 on Kubernetes-Node-1:
    - eth0: 10.1.1.2/24

Kubernetes-Node-2:
   - eth0: 192.168.0.3/24
   - docker0: 10.1.3.1/24

Pod2 on Kubernetes-Node-2:
   - eth0: 10.1.3.2/24

so we have following topology:
Pod1---Kubernetes-Node-1---Kubernetes-Node-2---Pod2

I want that  Pod1 and Pod2 can send each other multicast packages (on 228.8.8.8:45588), for Cluster-Discovery.

So I configured 2 routes with smcroute on Kubernetes-Node-1 and Kubernetes-Node-2:

mroute from eth0 group 228.8.8.8 to docker0
mroute from docker0 group 228.8.8.8 to eth0

If I create multicast-packages direct on eth0 of kubernetes-node-1 (mcsender -t32 -ieth0 228.8.8.8:45588), the packages get to eth0 on kubernetes-node-2, then over the mroute to docker0 on Kubernetes-node-2 and then to eth0 on Pod2.

The Problem occurs when the packages are created on Pod1:
Pod1 creates packages, that can be seen with tcpdump on kubernetes-node-1 on docker0 and because of the mroute also on eth0. Unfortunately the packages can't be seen on kubernetes-node2 - not on eth0 and not on docker0...

Has anyone ideas what the problem might be?

On Kubernetes-Node-1:

```
ip mroute
    (10.1.1.2, 228.8.8.8)          Iif: docker0    Oifs: eth0



netstat -nrv
        Kernel IP routing table
        Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
        0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
        192.168.0.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
        10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
        4.5.5.1         10.1.1.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 docker0
```

In the end there could be more Kubernetes-Nodes running Pods, that should commuticate over Multicast.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You don't provide enough information. How are the devices connected in your network (diagram)? What is your router model and configuration? Have you properly configured the multicast source and destination applications (subscribed to the multicast group)?

Comment: You need to setup multicast routing (PIM)  Simply adding mroute's won't make those two machines forwarders.

Comment: If mroute's not enough, why is it working from kubernetes-node-1 to Pod2? There the traffic gets forwarded, or am I wrong?

Unfortunately I have no Information about the router between Kubernetes-node-1 and Kubernetes-node-2, only that both machines are VM's running on openstack

Comment: Please post output of "cat /proc/net/ip_mr_cache" on Kubernetes-Node-1 as well.

Comment: "_I have no Information about the router between Kubernetes-node-1 and Kubernetes-node-2_" Unfortunately, questions about networks over which you have no control are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several issues:

1. I'm not sure about your topology, but am wild guessing it is:

   Pod1 ---- Kubernetes-Node-1 ---- Kubernetes-Node-2 ---- Pod2
2. This looks like a multicast loop to me:

   mroute from eth0 group 228.8.8.8 to docker0 mroute from docker0 group 228.8.8.8 to eth0
3. Check that your UNICAST routing tables towards the multicast source is correct. Does Kubernetes-Node-2 have UNICAST route for Pod1's address?

If you take advice, I think that running OSPF+PIM+IGMP is usually more practical than static multicast routing.

Comment: I thought smcroute can detect loops. But even with one mroute from docker0 to eth0 on kubernetes-node-1 and and one mroute from eth0 to docker0 on kubernetes-node-2 it's not working.

Comment: Did you check unicast routing? Please post outputs for both "ip mroute show" (kernel multicast table) and "netstat -nvr" (unicast routing table)

Answer (score 0):

A router/gateway doing inter-LAN routing needs to have PIM-DM ("Dense Mode", which assumes that there will be significant clumps of users of the same multicast group and "Cluster-Discovery" seems fitting here).  In the Linux kernel, you will notice that these options don't appear. This is because the protocol itself is handled by a routing application, such as Zebra, mrouted, or pimd. However, you still have to have a good idea of which you're going to use, to select the right options in the kernel.

Re endpoints: You have to tune your radio to hear a program that is transmitted at some specific frequency, in the same way you have to "tune" your kernel to receive packets sent to an specific multicast group. When you do that, it's said that the host has joined that group in the interface you specified.

You can do this using the `ip maddr add` command.

SYNTAX

`ip maddr [ add | del ] MULTIADDR dev STRING`

DESCRIPTION

It attaches/detaches a static link layer multicast address to listen on the interface. Note that it is impossible to join protocol multicast groups statically. This command only manages link layer addresses.

```
address LLADDRESS (default)
    the link layer multicast address. 
dev NAME
    the device to join/leave this multicast address.
```

EXAMPLES

Example for a wired connection:

`ip maddr add ff02::fb dev eth0`

Example for a wireless connection:

`ip maddr add 224.0.0.251 dev wlan0`

source [[Linux built-in or open source program to join multicast group?](https://superuser.com/questions/324824/linux-built-in-or-open-source-program-to-join-multicast-group)]